# Foreman pages fail to load

Tags: json, foreman, offlineapps, bastion

I just installed Foreman 3.3 with Katello 4.5 in an offline environment.

And in the pages below, I have a blank screen with some console output errors (see screenshots below).

It's seems that the pages fail to load due to Bastion UI or an error in the JSON. But I still don't understand the issue.

Affected pages:

- [Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N5Bb.png)
- [Content View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoNT1.png)
- [Sync Plans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1J73.png)
- [Lifecycle Environments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y33p3.png)
- [Content Credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ryHO.png)
- [Activation Keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqGvL.png)
- Deb Packages
- Container Image Tags
- Files
- Packages
- Errata
- Content Hosts
- Host Collections

Console output errors :

```
Cette page utilise la propriété non standard « zoom ». Envisagez d’utiliser calc() dans les valeurs des propriétés pertinentes ou utilisez « transform » avec « transform-origin: 0 0 ». products
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
products:51:1504
WARNING: Tried to load AngularJS more than once. katello:common-3245f69d8ef37312df4a.js:7:179007
Erreur dans les liens source : Error: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
URL de la ressource : https://172.20.10.2/webpack/katello/katello:common-3245f69d8ef37312df4a.js
URL du lien source : katello:common-3245f69d8ef37312df4a.js.map

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Bastion.capsule-content due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Bastion due to:
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: BastionConfig


https://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=Bas…ndle-v10.1.0-production-764404f58e4a47165b8a.js%3A1%3A920%0A
    A https://172.20.10.2/assets/bastion/bastion-a61e08734ad66c57bc535a2e0c25acc398bb44a8ac0e0ecd3541a62fa8bccafb.js:3
    c https://172.20.10.2/assets/bastion/bastion-a61e08734ad66c57bc535a2e0c25acc398bb44a8ac0e0ecd3541a62fa8bccafb.js:3
    ke https://172.20.10.2/assets/bastion/bastion-a61e08734ad66c57bc535a2e0c25acc398bb44a8ac0e0ecd3541a62fa8bccafb.js:3
    c https://172.20.10.2/assets/bastion/bastion-a61e08734ad66c57bc535a2e0c25acc398bb44a8ac0e0ecd3541a62fa8bccafb.js:3
    mt https://172.20.10.2/assets/bastion/bastion-a61e08734ad66c57bc535a2e0c25acc398bb44a8ac0e0ecd3541a62fa8bccafb.js:3
    t https://172.20.10.2/assets/bastion/bastion-a61e08734ad66c57bc535a2e0c25acc398bb44a8ac0e0ecd3541a62fa8bccafb.js:3
    q https://172.20.10.2/assets/bastion/bastion-a61e08734ad66c57bc535a2e0c25acc398bb44a8ac0e0ecd3541a62fa8bccafb.js:3
    <anonymous> https://172.20.10.2/assets/bastion/bastion-a61e08734ad66c57bc535a2e0c25acc398bb44a8ac0e0ecd3541a62fa8bccafb.js:26
    c https://172.20.10.2/webpack/foreman-vendor.bundle-v10.1.0-production-764404f58e4a47165b8a.js:173
    fireWith https://172.20.10.2/webpack/foreman-vendor.bundle-v10.1.0-production-764404f58e4a47165b8a.js:173
    ready https://172.20.10.2/webpack/foreman-vendor.bundle-v10.1.0-production-764404f58e4a47165b8a.js:173
    E https://172.20.10.2/webpack/foreman-vendor.bundle-v10.1.0-production-764404f58e4a47165b8a.js:173
    promise https://172.20.10.2/webpack/foreman-vendor.bundle-v10.1.0-production-764404f58e4a47165b8a.js:173
    a https://172.20.10.2/webpack/foreman-vendor.bundle-v10.1.0-production-764404f58e4a47165b8a.js:173
    js https://172.20.10.2/webpack/foreman-vendor.bundle-v10.1.0-production-764404f58e4a47165b8a.js:173
    n https://172.20.10.2/webpack/foreman-vendor.bundle-v10.1.0-production-764404f58e4a47165b8a.js:1
    js https://172.20.10.2/webpack/foreman-vendor.bundle-v10.1.0-production-764404f58e4a47165b8a.js:1
    n https://172.20.10.2/webpack/foreman-vendor.bundle-v10.1.0-production-764404f58e4a47165b8a.js:1
    0 https://172.20.10.2/webpack/foreman-vendor.bundle-v10.1.0-production-764404f58e4a47165b8a.js:398
    n https://172.20.10.2/webpack/foreman-vendor.bundle-v10.1.0-production-764404f58e4a47165b8a.js:1
    <anonymous> https://172.20.10.2/webpack/foreman-vendor.bundle-v10.1.0-production-764404f58e4a47165b8a.js:1
    <anonymous> https://172.20.10.2/webpack/foreman-vendor.bundle-v10.1.0-production-764404f58e4a47165b8a.js:1
bastion-a61e08734ad66c57bc535a2e0c25acc398bb44a8ac0e0ecd3541a62fa8bccafb.js:3:4735
```

Could you help? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error in the console log refers to the wrong file. The error was in the Katello dictionary, `/usr/share/gems/gems/katello-4.5.0.rc1/local/fr`.

In French, we use this special character  `'` and it causes this bug; so I removed it (see screenshot) and restarted foreman: `foreman-maintain service restart`.

[FR Dictionnary Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm2tf.png)